# Selenium - Declaring IWebElement variables vs calling functions from driver

Tags: performance, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

I've been using Selenium to write some automated tests for my environment. Currently, I am declaring IWebElement variables that reference a web element by it's XPath. Would it be more efficient and better practice just to call the click/clear/send key functions from the WebDriver?

**Current Method:**

```
firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
IWebElement elem = firefox.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@type='text']));
elem.sendKeys("Hello StackOverflow!");
```

**Alternative:**

```
firefox = new firefoxDriver();
firefox.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[@type='text'])).sendKeys("Hello Stackoverflow!");
```

I'd appreciate any advice and comments, thank you.

Comment: It's completely the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Would it be more efficient and better practice just to call the click/clear/send key functions from the WebDriver"*

You are not calling it from WebDriver. You use `RemoteWebElement: IWebElement` in both samples.
So it's completely the same. Difference is only in readability.

Comment: ...well readability and whether or not you want/need a variable storing the element. If you are going to use it again, you should store it in a variable for later use. If you don't need to use it again, there's really no point in storing it in a variable.

Comment: It barelly matters anything. After going out of scope this method GC will pick this objects (small wrappers actually that has only 2 reference fields) if needed. The question was in difference of calling that.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with your answer, I was just adding a comment on how I determine when to create a variable vs just use a one-liner.